# why the state always returns null in coprocessfunction in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I connected two streams and then called the `process` to implement my logic to get the results. Below is the flow of my Flink's code.

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<LifetimeIndex> autoEncodedRulStream = dividedStream.getSideOutput(autoEncodedRULModelTag)
                .keyBy(a -> a.getModelName() + "-" + a.getParameterId(), TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>() {
                }))
                .process(AssetParameterBundler.create())
                .connect(eventStream)
                .keyBy(a -> a.getAssetId() + "-" + a.getModelName(),b -> b.toString())
                .process(new Simulator())
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<LifetimeIndex>(Time.milliseconds(0L)) {
                    @Override
                    public long extractTimestamp(LifetimeIndex element) {
                        return element.getTime().getTime();
                    }
                });
```

In the `simulator()` class, I extended the `Coprocessfunction` in order to process two different streams which are eventStream and the mainStream. However, the state variables in the `simulator()` class always returns `NULL` even I update the state in the `processElement2`.

Below is the logic of the `simulator()` class. As you can see, there is no special logic, but the new logic is triggered when new data is coming into the event stream (But it always null so the if statement did not call).

```
public class AutoEncoderSimulator extends CoProcessFunction<BundledAssetParameters, String, LifetimeIndex> {
//    private transient MapState<String,String> mapState;
    private transient ValueState<String> state;

    private int numOfdataPoints = 0;
    private List<double[]> trainElementList;
    private List<Double> estimatedThresholdList;

    private ApmAutoencoder autoencoder;
    private double rulThreshold;
    private double trainDataPoint;
    private double lastHealthIndex;
    private AutoUpdate autoUpdate;

    @Override
    public void processElement1(BundledAssetParameters value, Context ctx, Collector<LifetimeIndex> out) throws Exception {
        LazyObject body = new LazyObject(value.getSpecifications().getModelOptions());
        rulThreshold = body.getDouble("rulThreshold");
        trainDataPoint = body.getDouble("trainDataPoint");

        numOfdataPoints = numOfdataPoints + 1;
        String event = state.value();
        trainElementList.add(value.getValues());


      //EVENT IS ALWAYS NULL!
        if (event != null) {
        }

        if (numOfdataPoints == trainDataPoint) {
            double[][] trainElement = ArrayUtils.toArray(new double[trainElementList.size()][]);
            for(int i=0;i<numOfdataPoints;++i){
                trainElement[i] = trainElementList.get(i);
            }
            AutoEncoderConfig autoEncoderConfig = new AutoEncoderConfig(trainElement.length,trainElement[0].length);
            autoencoder = new ApmAutoencoder(autoEncoderConfig);
            autoencoder.train(trainElement, 200);

            //auto update
            AutoUpdate autoUpdate = new AutoUpdate();
            double firstThreshold = autoUpdate.firstThreshold(autoencoder.getHealthIndex(trainElement), 10, 0.995);
            estimatedThresholdList.add(firstThreshold);

        } else if (numOfdataPoints > trainDataPoint) {
            double[] values = value.getValues();

        }
    }




    @Override
    public void processElement2(String value, Context ctx, Collector<LifetimeIndex> out) throws Exception {
        state.update(value);
    }




    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        ValueStateDescriptor<String> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                "1",
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>() {}));
        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);

        trainElementList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public AutoEncoderSimulator create(){
        return new AutoEncoderSimulator();
    }
}
```

I appreciate it if you could resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may have overlooked is that this is key-partitioned state -- so your `state` variable is not a String, but is actually a handle referring to a distributed key/value store (where the keys and values are Strings, in this case).

When you call `state.update(value)` in `processElement2`, the entry in this hash table for the key in context (the key for the current event) is updated. Are you sure that the same key is then in context when `state.value()` is called later on in `processElement1`?

Because the two connected streams are sharing state, it is imperative that both streams are keyed in compatible ways. I see that both streams are keyed by strings, but it's not clear that these strings are from the same keyspace. It doesn't seem likely that `modelName + parameterId` is going to equal `assetId + modelName`.

There's a [simple example of this pattern](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#connected-streams) in the Flink training site that you may find helpful.

Comment: From @TanmaySaha:Hi David: the link is broken. Pl update with the correct link. Thanks tanmay

Comment: @TanmaySaha I've updated the link. Thanks for the heads-up.